# Split a spring beans file into one file per bean

Tags: spring, xslt, spring-bean

Our application exports parts of its configuration as a set of beans. Each part of the configuration contains multiple similar items, each with a name

Ideally, the developers would export each item separately, and check them into our source code management under a meaningful name. Unfortunately, some developers are lazy, export the entire list as a single file, and check in something like 'export.xml" :(

I'd like to process such a file of beans and end up with one file per bean. Has anyone done something like this before? I guess I'm looking at an xslt but I don't know how to end up with multiple output files.

For extra credit :), I could use the value of a specified property within the bean to name the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Splitter" pattern:

http://www.eaipatterns.com/Sequencer.html

Apache Camel implements this:

http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html

... as does Spring Integration:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#overview-endpoints-splitter

... and JBoss Fuse:

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.3.1/html/Implementing_Enterprise_Integration_Patterns/files/Migrate-XPathSplitter.html

Pick your favourite...

Comment: OK, I agree that pattern describes my design problem. But I'm not sure any of the implementations you refer me to get me any closer to solving the problem of splitting up the beans file. Installing and configuring Camel to do this seems overkill...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

It can be done in XSLT 2.0 with the following XLST stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/beans/bean" xml:space="preserve"> 
            <xsl:result-document href='file{translate(normalize-space(./property[@name="name"])," ", "_")}.xml'
            doctype-public="-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
            doctype-system="http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</beans>
            </xsl:result-document>
         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This uses the value of the "name" property to construct the file name.